# How to order by the date of the last comment and sort by last created otherwise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a *Post* model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_names

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and a *Comment* model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id

  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Right now I know how to sort by date: `created_at ASC`, `created_at DESC`.

Now I would like to know, how to order by the date of the last comment and sort by last created otherwise?

Pretty much how StackOverflow does. For instance, if a question gets replied it is placed at the top, if other question is replied this one is placed on the top and so on. Questions are sorted ASC otherwise.

**Generated SQL:**

```
Started POST "/posts/30/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-12 11:59:32 +0800
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0zGpin7T/1aH/JBomGiqsEYCIgQ04HQWHZ/bIjm7WKs=", "comment"=>{"content"=>"sfsfwfewsdesd"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "post_id"=>"30"}
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "30"]]
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("content", "created_at", "post_id", "total_votes", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "sfsfwfewsdesd"], ["created_at", Mon, 12 Mar 2012 03:59:32 UTC +00:00], ["post_id", 30], ["total_votes", 0], ["updated_at", Mon, 12 Mar 2012 03:59:32 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 2]]
  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 30 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "posts" SET "comments_count" = COALESCE("comments_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "posts"."id" = 30
   (130.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/30
Completed 302 Found in 156ms (ActiveRecord: 133.4ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to add another datetime column to your post. Let's call it `content_changed_at` or something similar. In a new post it has value of `created_at`. Then you update it every time a comment gets posted. When you need to display posts, you just sort it by this column.

Here's untested code, but it should give you the idea.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_names

  before_create :init_sort_column

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  private 
  def init_sort_column
    self.content_changed_at = self.created_at || Time.now
  end
end

  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id

  after_create :update_parent_sort_column

  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user

  private
  def update_parent_sort_column
    if post
      post.content_changed_at = self.created_at
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do I have to create the content_changed_at column or use `attr_accessor` or `attr_writer` somewhere? Because I get this error: `undefined method `content_changed_at=' for #<Post:0x9a2e30c>`

Comment: You need real column in the database. A plain datetime column.

Comment: So the migration should be `add_column :posts, :content_changed_at, :datetime`?

Comment: Sorry I've been dealing with this other problem that is interfering with the ordering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655001/user-tag-subscription-system-interfering-with-will-paginates-order-attribute So I couldn't actually test your code.

Comment: I tested it. When I order posts as `content_changed_at DESC` newly created posts stack at the top but  posts with newly created comments stay in the same place. By the way, I added the **Generated SQL** in my question.

Comment: @alexchenco: that's bizarre. There's no `content_changed_at` in the generated sql. Maybe the sorting is overridden later?

Comment: I have no idea what that means :(

Comment: Instead of building the value in a hook, which will generate timestamps that might be seconds off from the `created_at`, you can have Rails handle this. Just redefine the `timestamp_attributes_for_create` method on your module and have it return `super + [:content_changed_at]`

Comment: Looks kinda unnecessary. Is this impossible to do with just mysql query or AR?

Answer (score 6):

If I were you I would add a last_comment_at:datetime field to your Post model, and be sure to update that datetime whenever a comment is created.

This way you can simply use `Post.order('last_comment_at, created_at DESC')`

Update - in reply to your comment asking about the migration you'd need, the following should generate the migration for you:

```
rails generate migration add_last_comment_at_to_posts last_comment_at:datetime
```

As others have noted, you can add an after_save call to your Comment model to update the last_comment_at field in your Post model. I would use something like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  after_save :update_post_last_comment_at

  private

  def update_post_last_comment_at
    self.post.touch(:last_comment_at) if self.post
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you give me more details about what to add in the migration file?