# Sort by latest created comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, comments

What i have created is a **"active"** field in my topics table which i can use to display the **active topics**, which will contain at first the time the topic was created and when someone comments it will use the comment.created_at time and put it in the active field in the topics table, like any other forum system.

I found i similar question here
[How to order by the date of the last comment and sort by last created otherwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654662/how-to-order-by-the-date-of-the-last-comment-and-sort-by-last-created-otherwise)

But it wont work for me, im not sure why it wouldn't. And i also don't understand if i need to use counter_cache in this case or not. Im using a polymorphic association for my comments, so therefore im not sure how i would use counter_cache. It works fine in my topic table to copy the created_at time to the active field. But it wont work when i create a comment.

Error:

NoMethodError in CommentsController#create

undefined method `topic' for

**Topic.rb**

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :forum_id, :title

  before_create :init_sort_column

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :forum
  validates :forum_id, :body, :title, presence: true

  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable

  default_scope order: 'topics.created_at DESC'

  private
  def init_sort_column
    self.active = self.created_at || Time.now
  end
end
```

**Comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :commentable_id, :commentable_type, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  before_create :update_parent_sort_column

  private

  def update_parent_sort_column
    self.topic.active = self.created_at if self.topic
  end

end
```

Comment: Why are you setting the `created_at` of `Comment` to the `active` value of it's `Topic`? Don't you want to set `topic.active` to the `created_at` of `Comment`?

Comment: self.topic.active = self.created_at if self.topic, tried this i still get the same error "undefined method `topic' for #<Comment:0x000000047bc858>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't realise you were using a polymorphic association. Use the following:

```
def update_parent_sort_column
  commentable.active = created_at if commentable.is_a?(Topic)
  commentable.save!
end
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: This doesnt create an error but is doesn't update the active field· Both the one you had before you edited and the one you have now.

Comment: Oops, forgot to add the `save!`.